# fb lint: Error Scraping Page: Bad Response Code

Tags: http, facebook-graph-api

All links for one of my domains now returns **`"Error Scraping Page: Bad Response Code"`** in **fb linter**. Any ideas why this would happen?

Here's an example of just one of the links that fb will not parse.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dnbradio.com%2Farchive%2F

Comment: How did u fix this ? - i have the same problem, and can see ur page is working atm. BR Jacob

Comment: Sorry I think it just fixed itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Simple Facebook Connect (WP Plugin) all the while, and I realized these few days it didn't work properly such as when I posted a link on my Facebook's Fan Page, the thumbnail went missing. I then checked the link using Facebook's debug tool, it showed me the same error message as yours.

After reading http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph, I realized the plugin does not generate tag for `fb:admins` (Or maybe it is a new rule from FB recently?). What I did is to manually change sfc-base.php in SFC, and added in the line `<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID1,USER_ID2"/>`. And now the error message has gone away.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is absolutely irrelevant. There are plenty of places/cases where admin_ids are not required.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but when I corrected on all pages number facebook app( &appId=YOURKEY ) to once (previously I had two) problem disappeared.

Check this line in code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
```

Sorry for English.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your application does **NOT** send any custom headers to the client.
Mine was sending such a header, which caused this same problem.

My header was:

```
header("X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block");
```

And yes, does your  tag have the required namespace declarations?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns# xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```